# How to use pytesseract to extract text from specific cordinates from image?

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract, text-extraction, python-tesseract

I have an image and i need to extract text from that image. 
The text i need to extract is from a specified co-ordinate location. Let say
cordinate=[ymin:ymax, xmin:xmax].
i have tried creating a new image using this co-ordinates and extracted the text. But the accuracy was very low due to the low quality of the new image.
So now i am researching on how to extract the text with in the co-ordinate values with out creating a new image.
I am using OpenCv to read the image and pytesseract to extract text.

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
import os
from PIL import Image
import sys
import numpy as np
# import textacy
config = ('-l eng --oem 2 --psm 1')

image = cv2.imread('C:/DocumentProcessing/IMAGE/2 (8).jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imwrite('gray.jpg',gray)

_,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,150,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV) # threshold
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS,(3,3))
dilated = cv2.dilate(thresh,kernel,iterations = 30)

_,contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilated,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
my_list = []
for contour in contours:
    [x,y,w,h] = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(127.5,0,255),1)
    new_image = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    cv2.imwrite(f"contoured-{y}-{x}.jpg", new_image)
    result = pytesseract.image_to_string(new_image,config=config)
```

Tesseract 4.0.0
pytesseract 0.3.0
OpenCv 3.4.3

Comment: Please provide example image and code you used.

Comment: @user898678 Question updated with code,Thank you

Comment: You did not provide/upload image. Some solutions depends on image quality.

Comment: @user898678 if the image quality is  good, then also i want to extract it from the co-ordinate points. If you have any idea please share

Comment: if the image quality is good then also OCR of part of image should be ok. If you do not provide image that enable us to reproduce problem, then you are alone with your problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use OPENCV to draw coordinates and then extract each section using tesseract